# "bash: jstack: command not found" error on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: java, linux, amazon-linux, jstack

On ec2 instance(Amazon Linux AMI) `jstack` is giving following error

`bash: jstack: command not found`

Java is installed on the machine

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Is there any reason to get error for `jstack` when java is already installed?

Comment: 'jstack' is not in $PATH : Example → `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-5.b12.el7_4.x86_64/bin/jstack` .......... The {java, javac} commands are in the PATH → See `/etc/alternatives`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDK is required for jstack. The instance only has JRE.